# app.config deployement in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, app-config

In my ASP.NET Core web app, I use a .NET framework library doing ODBC work.

So I need to have some configuration parameters that I can read from static methods in that library.

I found that I can have an app.config file and read the parameters like this

```
public class Config
{
     public static string siteLanguage = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["siteLanguage"];
}
```

This allows me to call the setting from a static method.

My problem is that the app.config file in my project, gets included in the PROJECTNAME.exe.config with every deployment. So it seems impossible to have different files per site. I have specified Build Action: None, and Do Not Copy. The file itself is not copied that way, but still included in the exe.config.

Any suggestions?

Pieter

Answer (score 0):

I think one solution could be to use your appsettings.json file rather than an app.config. You can create additional sub-files like appsettings.Development.json and appsettings.Production.json which can contain environment-specific settings. You could possibly do something like below in one of these files:

```
{
    "siteLanguage": "en"
}
```

More Info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration